# Facebook graph api - webhooks for comments on ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

We're using facebook graph api webhooks right now to get notified about someone commenting something on our page.

Right now we're running several ad campaigns, NOT boosting post, something we've created through Ads Manager, and want to get notified when someone comments an ad.

Is it anyhow possible? I've tried to google, read docs on webhooks or browse through webhooks list - without any luck

Thanks!